# Why ternary computers like Setun didn't catch on?

Tags: computer-architecture

Why [ternary computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer) like Setun didn't become popular despite being cheaper and more reliable than binary computers, and also having important [computational advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary#Computational_properties)? We could have had cheaper computers for everyone.
Edit: The answers to question about binary system do not resolve my question, since Setun, as I understand it, was based on some sort of binary circuit which used 2-bit combinations to represent the three values, the fourth combination wasn't used. Thus an argument about non-binary circuits being non-reliable doesn't apply to Setun.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Do Computers Use the Binary Number System (0,1)?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27656/why-do-computers-use-the-binary-number-system-0-1)

Comment: I think it is a bit like asking why the cars have 4 wheels instead of 3, 5, 6 and so on. Using computer with any base would be at high level very much the same. If computer used binary instead of ternary circuits - so you have binary emulating ternary operations - looks binary enough to me.

Comment: But Setun proved to be cheaper and more reliable than it's binary counterparts.

Comment: There were 47 machines produced, in Soviet Union - that on it's own tells the history of being not common. [Setun](http://www.irmielin.org/the-setun-conspiracy/) it will be hard to know the truth, but it seems that easy vs west might have something to do with it's popularity.

Comment: You might find the following video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thrx3SBEpL8

Comment: Ternary encodings are used a lot in hardware design for a variety of arithmetic computations, as a way to reduce carry propagation time. Look about carry-save/borrow-save adders, booth multipliers, SRT dividers,... All that low level stuff is entirely hidden to software though.

Comment: Setun was cheaper and more reliable than it's binary counterparts? That's a strong statement that needs strong evidence.