# Why is everything in computer science a power of $2$?

Tags: computer-architecture

I have noticed this strange thing.All things related to Computers come in values which are powers of $2$.For eg. Rams come in $2,4,8$ or $16$ GB,pendrives and memory cards also come in similar values.Computers are $8,16$ or $32$ or $64$ bit values.

Everything remarkably a power of $2$.Why is everything  $2^n$?

Why?Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1606827/5987698

Comment: 1) That's not true. My PC has 10 USB ports. 2) Even if real computers were built as you propose, that says *nothing* about computer science. 3) Agreed, duplicate. [This](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27656/why-do-computers-use-the-binary-number-system-0-1) may also be relevant.

Comment: Also, you may want to check out the [different definitions of, say, MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte#Definitions) to avoid confusion.

Comment: My computer has 10 GB of RAM, 3 MB of cache, and about 1,100 GB of storage. No powers of two anywhere.